# flash: as3 fullscreen mode problem - screen stays black

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen

i'm trying to create a fullscreen slideshow with as3. My problem now is that if I click the fullscreen button too quick (--> before the image has been loaded and hasn't therefore been added to the stage) the screen just stays black and nothing is working anymore (the following images aren't loading either.

Here is a demo of the problem:
http://eckquarters.com/watch.php?e6243444a9200c

Here is the code:

```
function onFirstSlideLoaded(e:Event):void
            {
                trace("FIRST SLIDE LOADED EVENT STARTED");
                firstImage = imageLoader.getBitmap(e.currentTarget.id);
                slides.push(firstImage);
                firstSlideLoaded = true;
                currentImage.addChild(firstImage);
                mcSlideHolder.addChild(currentImage);
                //den Inhalt des Loaders zu einem Container ausgeben
                trace("FIRST SLIDE ADDED EVENT FINISHED");
            }




function showFull(e:MouseEvent):void
{
                trace("F U L L ");
                stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
                var sw:Number = stage.fullScreenWidth;
                var sh:Number = stage.fullScreenHeight;
                //EventListener wenn sich Bildgröße verändert um Bildgröße zu aktualisieren;
                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, updateStage);              
                if(firstSlideLoaded)
                {       
                                    mcSlideHolder.addChild(currentImage);
                    stage.addChild(mcSlideHolder);
                    stage.addChild(fullScreenButton);
                    stage.addChild(slideButton);
                    stage.addChild(closeButton);
                    stage.addChild(saveButton);
                    stage.addChild(nextButton);
                    stage.addChild(prevButton);
                    firstSlideLoaded = false;
                    trace("child added");
                }
```

}

The bug has been driving me crazy for days and i'm pretty much out of ideas:) if anyone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add the event listener to your fullscreen button only *after* you've loaded the images?

Comment: thx alot for your reply!yah i already did that, it works just fine, however it isnt really a satisfying solution for me as the user experience suffers from it...

Comment: Then I suggest you test whether the image is loaded by storing it in a hash table once it is loaded. If it isn't loaded, put up a progress bar until you receive the event that tells you it is loaded.

Comment: As you can see, i add the current Image to the mcSlideHolder just when the onFirstSlideLoaded-event occurs ... so if you click the fullscreen button before it has finished loading the image it will add it afterwards when it's loaded ... so the image must be loaded then ... but why does the screen stay black???